# CKEditor set focus using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, angular-directive

I am using CKEditor with AngularJS. Now I have a page which loads the instance of CKEditor, but initially the Editor is hidden . The Editor will be shown when we click on button.The HTML of editor is loaded from a directive. So, I want  to focus inside the textarea of Editor when the editor is shown after button click.

Comment: can you give a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this directive with associated html attribute:

```
.directive('autofocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function($scope, $element) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $element[0].focus();
      });
    }
  }
}])

<div class="col-xs-11">
    <textarea type="text" autofocus ck-editor id="storyContent" ng-model="story.Content" required="" placeholder="Content" class="form-control" ></textarea>
</div>
```